# Spread link over whole div while containing Child-Nodes within div in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm Building an React-App for an editable Dashboard-Link Collection, the Code-Snippet below makes my brain hurt because in plain HTML and CSS the buttons are perfectly in the aspect-ratio of the Dashboard Element, But in the rendered React-App they're below the "dashboard-element" square. The HTML Code for the "dashboard-element"
gets generated from one Component and is exactly the same as in the snippet below. Is there maybe another way for the CSS to format it? The result should be the same as shown in the example, but I have no better styling idea how to solve this problem, or any idea why it works in plain but not for the generated html.

```css
 :root {
    --body-bg: #1F2428;
    --dashboard-element-bg: #2A2E32;
    /* --hover-highlight: #282E34; */
    --highlight: #4A5158;
    --border-radius: 8px;
}
     
.dashboard-list {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    max-width: 1000px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 20px;
    row-gap: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

.dashboard-element {
    background-color: var(--dashboard-element-bg);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: stretch;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    border-color: #3A444C;
    text-align: center;
}

.dashboard-element a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    font-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dashboard-element .btns {
    display: flex;
}

.dashboard-element .rmv-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
}

.dashboard-element .edit-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-list">
    <div class="dashboard-element">
      <a class="dashboard-link" target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
        <h6>Google</h6>
      </a>
      <div class="btns">
        <button class="edit-button">Edit</button>
        <button class="rmv-button">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="editmode">Toggle Editmode</button>
```

Comment: Is there any CSS generated by, or included elsewhere, by the component(s) involved? If you you right click, and 'inspect element,' what CSS does your browser's dev tools say is being applied? Check that the rules you expect to be applied are applied, or try to adjust the selector specificity so that it does apply.

Comment: Ok thanks I think i got it, because I added a motion animation which created a border-box div element parent to the "dashboard-element"